# Nested json serialization in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Class like so:

```
public class Wrapper<T>{

@JsonProperty
public Creds credentials;

public T data;

}
```

which, when serialized returns JSON like so:

```
{
  "credentials" : {
           "token": "xxxxx"
     },
  "data": {
          "A": "3",
          "Sub": {
                   "X": "something",
                   "Y": "something else"
               }
         }
}
```

I would like to move the contents of "data" up and return the JSON like so:

```
{
  "credentials" : {
           "token": "xxxxx"
     },
          "A": "3",
          "Sub": {
                   "X": "something",
                   "Y": "something else"
               }
}
```

Any pointers on how to achieve that? I've tried using the attribute below and overriding the toString on each Type of 'T', but that did not work.

```
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the following attribute to the "data" property.

```
        @JsonUnwrapped
```